# Python: Generate 2D points / clusters

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, cluster-analysis

I try to write an algorithm for clustering, now I like to create some easy 2D test cases: I like to generate points in `[0, 1]x[0, 1]` that build clusters.

E.g. something like this:
[image]

It would be better if the clusters have different (but random) shapes, e.g. like:[image]

Is there an easy way to do this with python / numpy? Unfortunately the generation must be very efficient. I wrote some code, but the clusters always have the same shape and they are often far away from each other. Probably already a nice algorithm exists?

Thank you

Comment: "Very efficient" generation is debatable. You can create random polygons and generate points only inside it. You would get random shaped clusters but it would imply some heavier operations than just generating a few numbers based on a distribution. Is this within the acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a packaged way to do this.  However, the generation algorithms aren't that hard to write.  The first one appears to be a Gaussian distribution in each dimension (X and Y), repeating the generation for each of three centroids.  Alternately, perhaps it's a uniform direction, with a "decay function" distance.

The second is a pair of sets: choose the radius from a Gaussian with a small variance, while the direction is uniform over the full circle.  Do that for mean radius 1 and mean radius 3.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: It helps, thanks:)! But the second example should be more general, the clusters should have any shapes (not only circles). But I think this cannot be easily done?

Comment: No -- there is no *algorithm* for "any shapes".  Generalize this just a little: "Can someone give me the algorithm to give me whatever output I want?  Even better, is there a Python package to do that?"  Information theory proves this to be impossible in very few steps.  :-)

Comment: ok, thanks;) probably I should have replaced "any shape" with "as many shapes as possible with a minimal complex algorithm";) but it seems that the simple gaussian clusters already produce reasonable test data:) thanks:)!

Comment: Right.  We can get most of what we need with simple combinations of uniform, Gaussian, exponential, and Poisson.